# I Want to show a notification every day to user in Windows Phone Silverloght 8.1

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, toast

I am new in windows Phone development and i working on Windows Phone 8.1 silver light application.

I want every day at a specific time the user see a new information from my application as a notification.

I try to search about Toast notification, MPN and WNS and other notification ways but i am very conflict and i don't know what is the right way of doing that so if any one can help me for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a periodic background task:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977059.aspx

You can then present a toast notification once 24 hours are over.